# bower install - Cannot find module 'tough-cookie'

Tags: gulp, bower, nunjucks, bower-install

I am getting an error and I don't know what to make of it. I'm clone a project then run
`npm install`. There is no problem but when i run `bower install` i am getting this error. How can i fix this?

Comment: Why you need bower packages?

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov It was used in the project I wanted to set up. 
I can not compile the project

Comment: Why did you think that `tough-cookie` dependency is come from `nunjucks`?